# How to handle if does not have a "current" tenant?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using Spatie laravel-multitenancy. laravel v8

I'm not defined domain one.localhost and now I'm getting an error. so how to handle the error.
error is

> Spatie\Multitenancy\Exceptions\NoCurrentTenant The request expected a
> current tenant but none was set. http://one.localhost:8000/

web.php

```
Route::domain('{tenant}.localhost')->middleware('tenant')->group(function(){
Route::get('/', function ($tenant) {
    return $tenant;
    // return view('welcome');
});
```

});

```
Route::domain('localhost')->group(function(){
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

});

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
return view('dashboard');})->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: Did you add this trait `use usesLandlordConnection;` in your model??

Comment: @FaridVatani in which model I use that trait?  http://one.localhost:8000/ => one is random subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am facing the same problem and after Debugging I found that I missed domain in tenants table [image]

please add "one.localhost" in tenants table and everthing will be fine

if you don't have tenants table please run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Multitenancy\MultitenancyServiceProvider" --tag="multitenancy-migrations"
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/landlord
```

Actually this package also provide Exception Handling if tenant did not exist. You can study more in these links

```
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/basic-usage/automatically-determining-the-current-tenant
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/advanced-usage/ensuring-a-current-tenant-has-been-set
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i get same error and i solve it by add the handle exception for NoCurrentTenant
got to Handler.php and try this register function:

```
 $this->reportable(function (NoCurrentTenant  $e) {
        abort(404);
    });
```